# Second argument Run[]

Tags: undocumented, run

Run officially takes only one argument. I encountered code with `Run[command, "Text"]`, is this a mistake or is the second argument meaningful? If so what does it do? (It still works with the second argument and gives as far as I can see the same result.).

Comment: I do not see the same results in my testing... `Run["date"]` returns `0` for me, `Run["date", "Text"]` returns `256`. Mathematica 11.3 on macOS.

Comment: @user6014, Ah, you are right. I did not really pay to much attention to it and tested it with something that returned 256 for both. Which I now understand is actually like 1 a failure and so not a good test. (I wrongly assumed it was 256 because I used a command that did not actually do anything except open a help page and I thought that 256 was maybe the exit code for that kind of thing.)